# Twitter request API and hashtags

Tags: api, rest, twitter, hashtag

Here's what I need.

I need to use

https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?........
query to retrieve tweets with specific hashtags only.

Currently I can specify include_entities=true but seems I have no way of specifying which particular hashtags I am after.

So the questtion is:

Is there a workaround/solution here or do I have to get all the tweets and filter out the ones with the hashtags I am looking for?

Basically I'd like to be able to call

https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?include_entities=true&screen_name=my_screen_name&hashtag=my_hash_tag&count=10
and get the 10 latest tweets from @my_screen_name that do have the #my_hash_tag.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your only way will be to get all the tweets using the query
https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?include_entities=true

then check (for all the result set) in the entities.hashtags part, if they contain your desired hashtag

Comment: Yep G.Ahmed that's what I am doing now. Not effective and somewhat ugly solution, but I guess that's the only option I can have at the moment.